# remapped shift key not working

Tags: shortcut

My shift key is not working anymore, so I remaped it on the little "2" key just under the escape key using keytweak . The remapping worked in all programs I used but not in Blender apparently .. I can't use shortcuts using shift . Thanks for any suggestions .

Comment: Hello Nathan! Sorry for your loss (
What do you mean by «the little "2" key just under the escape key» ? On my keyboard under the escape key settled ~
Have you tryed to remap some shortcut in blender keymap to «the little "2" key»? What happened?

Comment: hi, well it's the key with the "square" symbol , square as in "three squared equals nine" . I did not remap any shortcut in Blender because I don't want to do it manually every time I need a shortcut . But I found kind of a solution actually . Thanks for your answer !

Comment: Just get a new keyboard.

Comment: it's not on a desktop computer first , and second why throw away an object which can still do the job ?

Comment: You can always use an external keyboard on a laptop.

Comment: you're not helping and I have the solution , thanks .

Answer (score 0):

with autohotkey , I was able to remap my shift key and it works with blender , I couldn't find the "squared" key so I remap shift on the "left window" key .
To do it you must download autohotkey then create a new script and put in :

LWin::LShift